# Why getting out of memory error in Spark jobs?

Tags: apache-spark

In spark jobs, there are multiple reasons to get out of memory error, mostly when the shuffle size is large. However the expected behaviour from spark jobs is to spill on disk whenever the data (either cached data or shuffle data) does not fit into the executor memory, so theoretically we should never see an out of memory issue. But apparently this is not the behaviour in practice. What is the reason?